# Reading numbers from a text file that includes letters and numbers

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have a log file (txt file)  that i want to read only specific lines from. These lines include a specific set of words followed by number.

For example, the lines that i want to read from the file read:

- 10:03 Total query took 238.9 mili
- 10:08 Total query took 659.8 mili

How do I write a code that takes only the time the `query` executions took (the mili) and add them up?

I got down the part of reading from the text file only the lines that include "Total query took", but I'm stuck from here

Comment: What have you done so far? Any efforts?

Comment: Please show (a part of ) your input `file` .

Comment: I got the part of reading the file using StreamReader and   printing only the lines that include "total query took" but i cant understand how to extract the numbers that follow those words

Comment: use System.IO.File.ReadLine(..) in a foreach to readlines  and use Regex or use string.contains("Total query took")==false.

Comment: You might want to play around with a combination of [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k8b1470s.aspx), [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.char.isdigit.aspx) and [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aka44szs.aspx). But watch out for the *culture specific* [DecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the text from the file. [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can do this. Look at the example in the link.
2. Get the number from the text. You can use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as well as [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want to be fancy you can even use [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this is overkill.
3. Add the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy with `Regular Expression`. I guess the line is on a string.

```
String str_line = "your line from file" ;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d.*");
Match match = regex.Match(str_line);
if (match.Success)
{
    //you got the value with "match.Value;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public decimal ReadMilliseconds()
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(@"\path\to\file");
    decimal totalMilliseconds = 0;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<ms>\d*\.?\d*)\s*mili");

        if (!match.Success) continue;

        decimal value = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["ms"].Value, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

        totalMilliseconds += value;
    }

    return totalMilliseconds;
}
```